# Bootstrap 3: Hide elements on devices smaller than tablets without using 2 classes bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to hide element on devices smaller than tablets (`col-sm-* & col-xs-*`) without using 2 bootstrap classes `visible-md visible-lg` on the element with bootstrap 3's predefined classes:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 visible-md visible-lg"> ..</div>
```

Thanks
dkj

Comment: Use " hidden-xs "  class

Comment: That does not hide on tablets (col-sm*). Any other ideas.

Comment: You must put two classes for this if you are using boostrap<4. So you need to use " visible-md visible-lg " or " hidden-sm hidden-xs ". And if you are use bootstrap 4 then you can do this using one class. please see this http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) the visible (and hidden) classes only show for that media query size, if you wish to extend the classes to allow you to do this with a single class you can but this would require you to have a basic understanding on media queries and css3 (sass or less if you use a preprocessor).

You could just use the `hidden-xs`class to hide it below the `col-sm-*` query range as @Vijay Maheriya said in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one (or a few) element(s) you want to hide/show selectively, it's probably easiest/best to just use both classes.  If you are doing this with several elements and prefer to keep your markup cleaner, you can easily just create your own class for this.  For instance:

```
.hidden-sm-xs {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
.hidden-sm-xs {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

If you've customized the Bootstrap breakpoints, note that you will need to adjust 992px to match your custom breakpoint.  As others have noted, you could just override one of Bootstrap's existing classes, but I prefer to just create a new one...It's the same amount of CSS, and you never know when you might actually want `hidden-xs` to hide only on the smallest screens like it was intended. But if you've overridden it, you'd have a lot of refactoring to do.

Comment: This is nearly what I think is the correct way to do it. and more importantly it looks cleaner...Wonderful..

Comment: Is there something more you think is needed? (looking to understand why 'nearly' correct...)

Comment: I don't know, may be I am looking for a smarter answer. BTW, your's is a pretty smart answer too.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, forget about the classes and just do:

```
.your-selector {
  display: none;
}
@media(min-width: 992px) {
  .your-selector {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Use the classes for more specific cases when realy needed.

Comment: This would hide all elements that use `.col-sm-8`

Comment: @ZachariaSamuelGrierson yeah duhhh, I should answer it in context.